# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in UsersController#create ... missing required keys: [:id], possible unmatched constraints: [:locale]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-i18n

I had some nice form that had been working well, but once I add some translations, ***I get following error:***

[image: Error Message]

Here are some important files I have:

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    get 'sessions/new'
    get 'teamscrs/index'
    get 'teamscrs/new'
    get 'teamscrs/show'
    get 'profile', to: 'teamscrs#show'
    get 'login', to: 'sessions#new'
    get 'users', to: 'users#new'
    delete 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'    
    post 'login', to: 'sessions#create'

    resources :users    

    root 'teamscrs#index'
  end

  match '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}"), :via => [:get, :post]
  match '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}"), :via => [:get, :post]

  #get '/teamscrs' => 'teamscrs#home'
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @user= User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        if @user.save
            flash[:success] = t(".sukces")
            redirect_to @user
        else
            flash.now[:danger] = t(".fail")
            render 'new'
        end

    end

private 
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :set_locale
  helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def logged_in?
    !!current_user
  end

  def must_login
    if !logged_in?
        flash[:danger] = t(".mustlogin")
        redirect_to login_path
    end
  end

private
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def default_url_option(options = {})
    {locale: I18n.locale}
  end

end
```

**users/new.html.erb**

```
...
        <%= form_with scope: :user,  url: users_path, local: true do |form| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= form.label(:name,t('.username'))%>
                <%= form.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <%= form.label(:email,t('.email'))%>
                <%= form.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <%= form.label(:password_digest,t('.pass'))%>
                <%= form.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>             
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <%= form.label(:password2, t('.passc'))%>
                <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>                
            </div>

            <%= form.submit t('.join'), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
        <% end %>
...
```

**users/show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <strong>Użytkownik:</strong>
  <%= @user.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>email:</strong>
  <%= @user.email %>
</p>
```

**config/environment.rb**

```
...
Rails.application.configure do |variable|
  config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**/*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
  I18n.available_locales = [:en, :pl]
  I18n.default_locale = :pl
end
...
```

I spent whole day reading stackoverflow, I18n guides and watching youtube videos. I'm just a beginner. Please support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing:

```
redirect_to @user
```

to:

```
redirect_to controller: 'users', action: 'show', id: @user.id
```

after I read that cause of implementing default_url_options, I have to explicitly let know Rails to pass the id

Answer (score 0):

In the users_controller.rb, there is one update method defined where redirect_to @user. This is in fact which is redirecting to some URL. But this error says this @user is no URL matching against this.

Solution:
The best way to write routes is to run rails routes. From there copy the path for `user#index` and paste in the arguments of `redirect_to`.

it may be like

```
redirect_to user_path
```

or

```
redirect_to users_path
```

or

```
redirect_to user_index_path
```